# Does Q in Star Trek always have blue lips?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager

In *Star Trek: Voyager*'s "Death Wish" Q has blue lips. Is this in all appearances in Star Trek (TNG, Voyager,...) the case? Also, why are the lips blue?

Comment: He was asked this question at the [Calgary Comic-expo](http://mlp.derpynews.com/tara-strong-john-de-lancie-calgary-expo/). His answer to "*Why did they put lipstick on Q?*" was "***’Cause they went with my high heels.***"

Comment: I seemed to me that the blue lips went with his appearance as a terrestrial post-apocalyptic judge or whatever he was representing himself to be in the series premiere and finale episodes. Although Q has made other appearances with blue lips, I sometime wonder if it was due to confusion as to what his "true" appearance really should be.

Comment: The form "Q" takes is cosmetic as implied by the episode, [Déjà Q](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%C3%A9j%C3%A0_Q) in which another "Q" appears and remarks at the bipedal nature of their circumstance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A quick search of Q images reveals that he doesn't always have blue lips. It appears he tends to change his complexion depending on the role he is assuming.

That said, the picture below with the blue lips might be considered Q in his natural state, so perhaps they are indeed blue. As to why, I have no idea other than the fact that he is an omnipotent alien, and perhaps that is one of their features :)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't think Q had blue lips in his "natural state".  I think the Grand Inquisitor from the "Post-Atomic Horror", whom Q was imitating, wore blue lipstick as part of his costume.

Comment: I see I'm wrong.  Q was not portraying the Grand Inquisitor in "Death Wish", but he still had blue lips.
http://voy.trekcore.com/gallery/albums/2x18/deathwish_217.jpg
Also, the other member of the Q Continuum in that episode had blue lips as well.
http://voy.trekcore.com/gallery/albums/2x18/deathwish_196.jpg

Comment: You're doing more digging than me though :) +1

Comment: Remember that his first appearance aboard the Enterprise in "Encounter at Farpoint" was that bright floating object with three snakehead-like projections. One might argue that was Q's true appearance. Never mind the lipstick.

Comment: @AnthonyX I think you're thinking of his [Aldebaran serpent form](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Aldebaran_serpent) from "Hide and Q" (his second appearance)

Answer (score 1):

In the Star Trek Voyager episode "Death Wish" which features 2 members of the continuum, both have slightly blue stained lips, indicating a racial trait.

[image: Star Trek Voyager, death wish]

It's a little hard to see in the image but it's unmistakeable when watching the episode

Answer (score 0):

I never noticed his lip color:  The specifics of skin, hair, and eye color are especially superficial in the *Star Trek* universe.

I expect any unusual coloration is to reinforce a being's other-worldliness.  Q is definitely not human and should not be confused as such.  He may as well have a diagonal purple mohawk.

Answer (score -4):

He doesn't eat, once called it a 'vile human habit'. So it can be assumed he doesn't have a circulatory system or his circulatory system is simply not working which would normally feed his body nutrients.

With this, he can also survive in space unassisted (numerous episodes) - which suggests he doesn't breathe or process oxygen.

Blood needs oxygen replenishment to turn from blue to red. As well as a functional circulatory system that replenishes the nutrients which further discolors the blood to blue. Neither of which he has.

So his lips. Without 'red blood' circulating, are blue.

He's immortal. I suspect that's just another way of saying he's undead.

A pretty fantastic attention to detail on the writer's parts, don't you think?

Comment: Using that anatomical basis, his entire skin would be pale white and his fingertips blue too. The pinkish hue to white people depends on red blood pumping through capillaries.